# Desktop Icon link

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is an option of setting an auto icon link of my application in the user's desktop, after installing it?

The only way I know to do it, is that the user could drag it manually to his desktop from the applications list. Is there any way of doing it automaticlly for the user(withouth his touch) ?

Thanks,

Moshic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't do that automatically!!!
Let the user choose wether or not he want your shortcut!

Here is the code you need:

```
        //Create shortcutIntent here with the intent that will launch you app.
        Intent shortcutIntent = (...)
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        final Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        // Sets the custom shortcut's title
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,sName);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, icon);

        // add the shortcut
        intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Don't forget an extra permission in the Manifest!

```
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it automaticlly when the user INSTALL the app?

Comment: I've never heard about self-launched app In android...

You can execute this piece of code at the first manual launch of your application.

Comment: What I do for my application is I create a boolean preference "actiondone", that is by default "false"

If (!actiondone)
then I set this preference to true and make my "firstboot" action.

Hope you are familiar with the preferences...

Comment: http://downloadandroid.info/2010/06/how-to-check-if-its-the-first-run-of-your-app/

Comment: And how would you delete the shortcut?